# All strings with length of the longest string

Tags: javascript, string

Hei, I have this function:

```
function frame(string) {
  var words = string.split(" ");
  var longestWord = 0;
  var y = "*";

  //Find the longest word from the string
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > longestWord) {
      longestWord = words[i].length;
    }
  }
  console.log(y.repeat(longestWord + 4));
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    console.log(y + " " + words[i] + " " + y);
    //words[i].length = longestWord;
  }
  console.log(y.repeat(longestWord + 4));
}
```

I want that all the string has the same length as the longest string. The rest is working good. The code that is commented out is the one i tried last but is not working. 
Apparently, the logic is not totally correct, but what I am missing?
Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to do, get `words[i]` in the middle? Like `console.log("* "+ words[i] + " ".repeat(longestWord - words[i].length) + " *")`?

Comment: Basically would be to do a frame. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the space left to fill and repeat it as below.

```js
function frame(string) {
  var words = string.split(" ");
  var longestWord = 0;
  var y = "*";

  //Find the longest word from the string
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > longestWord) {
      longestWord = words[i].length;
    }
  }
  console.log(y.repeat(longestWord + 4));
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    spaceLeft = longestWord - words[i].length;
    console.log(y + " " + words[i] + " ".repeat(spaceLeft) + " " + y);
    //words[i].length = longestWord;
  }
  console.log(y.repeat(longestWord + 4));
}

frame('skfj dslfska sadflkdsflkdsnf ldsknflskdnaf dslkf')
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in JS, you can't just overwrite the length attribute ;)

Do you mean, that you need padding after the word up to the length of the longest word? If I understood it correctly, then try something like this:

```
console.log(y + " " + words[i].padEnd(longestWord, " ") + " " + y);
```

This looks like the easiest way, but consult [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=padEnd), if all your browsers are covered.

Answer (score 2):

I would be tempted to get rid of some of the `for` loops to help readability. You can use `Math.max` and `map` to find the longest word and `padEnd` to fix the length:

```js
function frame(string, y = '*') {
  var words = string.split(" ");
  let longestlength = Math.max(...words.map(w => w.length))
  let header = y.repeat(longestlength + 4)
  return [
    header,
    ...words.map(word => `${y} ${word.padEnd(longestlength, ' ')} ${y}`),
    header
  ]
}

console.log(frame("hello the word javascript is long").join('\n'))
```

Comment: Yes I have been trying to work more with map than with for loops and indeed works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first loop  for finding the max length of word seems right in second loop you can use if statement 
All you have to do is that 
First define an array 
let a=[]
In second loop in the commented part write

```
if(word[I].length == longestlength){a.push(word[I])}
```

After that you get array containing word whose length is equal to max length 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```js
function frame(string) {
  var words = string.split(" ");
  var longestWord = 0;
  var y = "*";

  //Find the longest word from the string
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > longestWord) {
      longestWord = words[i].length;
    }
  }
  console.log(y.repeat(longestWord));
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    console.log(words[i] + y.repeat(longestWord - words[i].length));
    //words[i].length = longestWord;
  }
}

frame('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit')
```

maybe something like this, now every word has same length as the longest one, empty space is filled with `*`

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline:

```js
function frame(string) {
  var words = string.split(" ");
  var longestWord = "";
  var y = "*";

  //Find the longest word from the string
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > longestWord.length) {
      longestWord = words[i];
    }
  }
  console.log("Longest word is: " + longestWord)
  console.log(y.repeat(longestWord.length + 4));
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    // Get the difference between the word and the longest word
    var diff = longestWord.length - words[i].length;
      // Pad the words with the right amount of spaces to make up the difference
      console.log(y + " " + words[i] + " ".repeat(diff) + y);
  }
  console.log(y.repeat(longestWord.length + 4));
}

frame("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
```